# Ruby on Rails: bad username / password? (535 Auth failed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, sendgrid

I just finished my ruby foundations coursework at Bloc and I'm starting to bury my head into rails development. Things were going smooth until I hit this snag with devise and confirmation emails. I tried googling and looking around at some other questions but couldn't really find any that gave me anything that I could pull from and apply to my situation.

I'm receiving the following error when signing up for an account.

## Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

### 535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password

---

Error extracted from source around line #976

```
def check_auth_response(res)
  unless res.success?
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError, res.message
  end
end
```

---

From other posts I know you'll probably want to see that I have a config/initializers/setup_mail.rb file that looks like this:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address:        'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port:           '587',
    authentication: :plain,
    user_name:      ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    password:       ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    domain:         'heroku.com',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

---

And here's an application.yml file EXAMPLE:

```
SENDGRID_PASSWORD: 
SENDGRID_USERNAME:
SECRET_KEY_BASE:
```

---

also I have the following in my config/environments/development.rb before anybody suggests it:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000'}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
# Override Action Mailer's 'silent errors' in development
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

---

If there's any other files that you'd like to see let me know and I'll add them to this post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Congrats and welcome to the world of hacking on cool things.

The error you are getting means that the SendGrid server received a bad username + password combo.

Chances are your environment variables are empty and your `application.yml` file isn't being loaded properly with your SendGrid username + password.

You can confirm this by printing them out somewhere in your code. In a controller works.

```
puts "SENDGRID_USERNAME: #{ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']}"
puts "SENDGRID_PASSWORD: #{ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']}"
```

I'd suspect that they are nil.

I'd recommend reading https://quickleft.com/blog/simple-rails-app-configuration-settings/ about how to get them sourced into your app.

Please let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: Great answer thanks @eddie.  I was starting to squirrel away some of these settings as commented lines in a `secrets.yml` file and then just manually setting in the shell with `export`.  Is there any reason at all to have a `secrets.yml` file or should I be merging all of this into `application.yml`?

Comment: The username and pass are not nil they show up as intended bud

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/eddiezane/rails-devise-sendgrid/commit/115f04f40078fbc22ab031c86f171a3aec4ce311) a minimum working example. Happy to take a look at what you have if you toss it up on GitHub.

Comment: @eddiezane ended up solving this by removing the sendgrid addon and unsetting user/pass variables then re adding the addon but instead this time using `heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter` rather than `heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter`

Comment: @JeffWilkey I just followed your suggestion and straight away see `An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create sendgrid:starter: Error Provisioning User - User status - banned`. For context, this is my first time using sendgrid and the sendgrid + heroku combo. Not great UX for either really.

Comment: If anyone else has this problem, best [contact sendgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642112/5783745)

Answer (score 6):

> Two-Factor Authentication is required as of Q4 2020, and all Twilio
> SendGrid API endpoints will reject new API requests and SMTP
> configurations made with a username and password via Basic
> Authentication.

I received a similar issue from an app I've been running for the last couple years. From now on, basic auth doesn't work, and you'll need to use an alternative auth mechanism. Heroku sendgrid auto-configuration on installation has not yet been updated to reflect this.

Source: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/upgrade-your-authentication-method-to-api-keys/

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was to use as username the id of my apikey, but this is wrong, the correct value user_name is 'apikey', (Literally 'apikey' string), as they say in their integration example,
https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/rubyonrails/
https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/smtp

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:user_name => 'apikey', # This is the string literal 'apikey', NOT the ID of your API key
:password => '<SENDGRID_API_KEY>', # This is the secret sendgrid API key which was issued during API key creation
:domain => 'yourdomain.com',
:address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
:port => 587,
:authentication => :plain,
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: Oh my god. Same for me!!!