# Error Provisioning User - User status - suspended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I created a new Sendgrid addon in Heroku:

```
heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter
```

After that, I entered my Sendgrid account and it said that my account was suspended (I just created, how is it suspended?)

So, I had a brilliant idea (NOT!): I've removed the addon and tried to create it again. Now I get the following error from Heroku:

```
 An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create sendgrid:starter: Error Provisioning User - User status - suspended
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of why this is happening? I am experiencing the exact same with each new SendGrid add-on automatically being suspended...

Comment: Not really... I had to contact them. I believe that there's nothing you can actually do. Tell them your problem via https://support.sendgrid.com

Comment: Great thanks, I contacted them and they have sorted it. Like you they wouldn’t say why which is not helpful to avoid again in future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, after some research, there is nothing that I could do. I contacted Sendgrid support (https://support.sendgrid.com) and they solved the problem (although they never told me what was wrong in the first place).

Comment: I'm having this issue now. The support team don't seem to understand. Did you say something specific to help them understand this issue?

Comment: I have sent the error that I got:  "An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create sendgrid:starter: Error Provisioning User - User status - suspended." They should know on their end what to do

Comment: I'm unable to even log in to their support pages!

Comment: @L.Youl, unfortunately that's the only way right now

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I just created a [sendgrid account](https://signup.sendgrid.com/) without heroku add-one, and, after following the intructions, I added the sendgrid code into my own code, and it's work.